# ironpython: any way to distinguish my methods from inherited methods in c# defined class?

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have defined a class with a single function. For example:

```
namespace my.namespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void some_func(string s1, string s2)
        {
            // more code here               
        }       
    }
}
```

I am able to load this object into an ironpython interpreter. I want to use introspection to get a list of methods that were implemented only in this class. In this example I want a list like `['some_func']`. Is there a way to do it?

If I do a `help(instance)` on this instance I get more-or-less what I want:

```
class MyClass(object)
 |  MyClass()
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __repr__(...)
 |      __repr__(self: object) -> str
 |  
 |  some_func(...)
 |      some_func(self: MyClass, s1: str, s2: str)
```

Of course, when I d a `dir(instance)` I get a lot of other functions:

```
>>> dir(instance)
['Equals', 'GetHashCode', 'GetType', 'MemberwiseClone', 'ReferenceEquals', 'ToString', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'some_func']
```

I want to know what instrospection method I need to use to get a list of only the functions unique to this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options.

You can (explicitly) implement the `IronPython.Runtime.IPythonMembersList` interface that way you can list whatever members you want to list.  It's as if you defined the `__dir__` method for your class.

```
public class MyClass : IronPython.Runtime.IPythonMembersList
{
    public void some_func(string s1, string s2) { }

    IList<object> IronPython.Runtime.IPythonMembersList.GetMemberNames(CodeContext context)
    {
        return new[] { "some_func" };
    }

    IList<string> Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.IMembersList.GetMemberNames()
    {
        return new[] { "some_func" };
    }
}
```

You could always define a public `__dir__` method for your class as well.  The return type could be anything really, but you'll probably want to return some collection of strings.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void some_func(string s1, string s2) { }

    public IEnumerable<string> __dir__()
    {
        return new[] { "some_func" };
    }
}
```

You always have the option to use regular .NET reflection.

```
from System.Reflection import BindingFlags

# you can omit the flags if you want all public .NET members
flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly

members = instance.GetType().GetMembers(flags)
dir_members = [ mi.Name for mi in members ]
print(dir_members)
```

Comment: That last solution using `System.Reflection` is very, very close to what I want. It's not quite perfect though -- when I ran the code my result included `".ctor"` in addition to `some_func`. I can filter that out easily enough. Thanks for the well thought out answer.

Comment: your example uses `GetMembers`; did you intend to use `GetMethods` instead? The latter seems to work better at least in my very simple case, in that it excludes the `.ctor` method.

Comment: Actually I did intend to use `GetMembers()` that way everything that is publicly accessible would be listed (including properties, fields, etc.).  You could easily filter out the constructors however: `[ mi.Name for mi in members if mi.MemberType != MemberTypes.Constructor ]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an IronPython interpreter handy to check if it works with .NET classes, but you can use:

```
print instance.__class__.__dict__
```

to get the members that are just part of that class. There will be some extra Python `__foo__` methods (like `__doc__`) that IronPython adds but those are easy to filter out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are right that this comes close to working. It includes a few extra function, but if I can assume that all instances of all classes return the same extra functions, I'm good.